# R Markdown PDF With Plotly not Centering

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm writing an Rmd which encorporates plotly objects on each page. I'm trying to get the object to more or less fill the page and be centered, but passing `fig.align = "center"` does nothing. Here's my YAML header:

```
---
geometry: margin=0.25in
classoption: landscape
graphics: yes
output: 
  pdf_document:
  fig_caption: yes
---
```

And here's what I'm trying to center it with:

```
{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.width = 11, fig.height = 8}
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
)
```

From what I can tell, there's no difference between `fig.align = "center"//"left"//"right"`.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I assume it's something to do with plotly html not being treated properly in the Latex context, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm aware that I can just write these plots to a png with `export` and then place those using Latex. This is not efficient, however, and slows my rendering down significantly.

Comment: Not sure what is happening there, before your plotly chunk can you use the command `\begin{center}` and immediately after `\end{center}` to see if it can center it that way?

Comment: Tried that, and nothing.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because you are making a PDF and do not need the interactivity of `plotly` can you switch to `ggplot` or base plots?

Comment: I am using plotly because this is part of a package that encorporates a dashboard. There are functions that create the plots, and the PDF is really just a backup in case a user wants to save the dashboard in the state it's in. So, in short, I have to use plotly for that, and I'd rather not make ggplot alternatives for every exhibit.